# Cannot Access RecordType.DeveloperName Field as System Admin

Tags: api, permissions, tooling-api

I'm a System Admin in an org and today our Flow was throwing errors saying no such field RecordType.DeveloperName. I tried running a SOQL query using that field in Developer Console and I get same error if I run the query using Tooling API. If I uncheck Tooling API query runs fine. The error from the Flow is below.

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:8 No such column 'Developername' on entity
>   'RecordType'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I can use the Tooling API in the SOQL to include all RecordType fields except the DeveloperName.

I don't know how these two errors are related but need to access RecordType.Developername in any case. Any thoughts on problem here?

Comment: is this V34 (summer 15 pre-release) or V33 or earlier?

Comment: Spring 15 release. V33. But also, Im not setting API version with any code. I'm just running a Flow and/or Dev Console

Comment: Not sure about the Flow part of this issue, but in Tooling API (v33 current & v34 Summer 15)  object RecordType does not have field "DeveloperName". Hence you can not query it using Tooling API. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/Content/tooling_api_objects_recordtype.htm

Comment: So this looks like a very unfortunate bug I'm afraid. I confirmed that running this in the Developer Console works as DeveloperName is GONE in v34. The problem is that the below conflicts. Furthermore the org is not upgraded to Summer '15 anyway AND when you look at the list of fields presented for RecordType in Flow FullName is not there, DeveloperName is, but the error is saying DeveloperName does not exist when running. We will talk with support today and update here accordingly. https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug that Salesforce has fixed with a patch release shortly after I posted it. While the Tooling API doesn't have DeveloperName field it should not have had anything to do with Flows and it did.